How to see material properties (colors) in main view
Newbie question: I am watching this excellent video by Ryan King to learn how to work with materials. His version of blender seems fairly close to mine. However: when he makes changes to a material, he sees an immediate change in the main view. His objects are colored. However, when I make changes to a material, they do not appear in the main view but only in the Render view when I press F12. This is slowing me down horribly!
I'm guessing that some default has changed recently that's giving me different behavior. In blender 4, what setting do I need to change to see colors and other material properties in the main view?
Blender 4.2.1
Mac OS 14.2.1
His world:

My world:


hello, it looks like you are in Solid view mode while he is in Material preview mode

Ryan has his viewport switched to Material Preview, unfortunately your setting is hidden in the screenshot but it looks like your in Solid shading mode, the button left from Material Preview.

Although you can have colored objects in Solid shading mode as well. More information about the different color modes in Solid you can find in my answer here: Can not display a single mesh as solid

And I actually like the "Rendered" mode even better.

@Joymaker Aha, okay. The different shading modes do serve different purposes though, they are not just there to choose which one you like better ;) One main thing is, the more complex the shading (wire to solid to preview to render), the higher the performance cost for example. So especially in very large scenes it might be more beneficial to work more smoothly than having it look nicer.
